# Notepad++ Search and Replace: delete 3 to 4 numbers after N in each row

Tags: replace, find, notepad++

I have a text file where almost all the lines start with the letter N followed by 3 or 4 numbers as below

```
N970 G2 X-1.0591 Y-1.7454 I0. J-.04
N980 G1 Y-1.7554
N990 X-1.0594 Y-1.7666
N1000 Z-.2187
N1010 Y-1.7566
```

How can I remove the N followed by the 3 or 4 numbers in Notepad++ to look like this? if i need to search twice (once for N### and then again for N####) that is fine also.

```
G2 X-1.0591 Y-1.7454 I0. J-.04
G1 Y-1.7554
X-1.0594 Y-1.7666
Z-.2187
Y-1.7566
```

the numbers go from 100-9990 in increments of 10 if that helps

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, I hope my answer meets all of your question's conditions. Let me know if the solution works for you and feel free to add additional constraints and ask questions in the comments. Also read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex that should work for your case:

```
^N[0-9]+\s*(.*)
```

It will match **every** line that starts with a capital letter N immediately followed by *one or more* digits. Matched results will include a single group which will contain the text you are looking for.

*Note that whitespaces between the N tags and the actual text will **not** be matched*.

Try it out in this [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/R560Ny/1)

**Breakdown**

```
^         # Assert position at the start of the line
N         # Matches capital letter 'N' literally
[0-9]+    # Matches any digit between 1 and unlimited times
\s*       # Matches whitespace between 0 and unlimited times
(.*)      # The rest of the text you are looking for
```

**Find/Replace**

- The regex will match each individual line so you can either select `Find Next` and then `Replace` and process your file one line at a time or you can choose `Replace All` to process the whole file at once.
- Substitution line (`Replace with:`) line should just include the first group ($1) which represents the rest of your text with N-prefix tags trimmed.
- Make sure that the `Search Mode` is set to `Regular expression`.

[image]